# angular best practice for select show options when other select changes

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i'm trying to build a select box that trigger show on options of other select in angular way.

the json that i use build select boxs is

```
[
{"item_id":1,"item":"rubber","type":"x","facility":"school a"},
{"item_id":2,"item":"pen","type":"x","facility":"school b"},
{"item_id":3,"item":"book","type":"y","facility":"school b"},
]
```

what i need is 3 select boxes, first one shows all unique `type`. in above json that would be 'x,y'.

when user select one of them, then it should show all unqiue `facility` values in other selectbox that has same type as selected.
--if user selected x, then it would show `school a` and `school b`

when user select facility, a 3rd selectbox show all uiqiue `item` as label, and item_id as value where facility = selected facility

```
<select ng-model="selected.type">
<!-- need to show unique types here -->
</select>

<select ng-model="selected.facility">
<option ng-repeat="s in json" ng-if='selected.type == s.type'>{{s.item}}</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selected.item">
<option ng-repeat="s in json" ng-if='selected.facility == s.facility'>{{s.item}}</option>
</select>
```

### Current solution

currently what i'm doing is that i wrote a filter

```
.filter('unique', function() {

        return function (arr, field) {
            var r = [],final=[];
            for(i in arr){
                if(r.indexOf(arr[i][field]) == -1){
                    r.push(arr[i][field]);
                    final.push(arr[i]);
                }
            }
            return final;
        };
    })
```

and doing

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="nrequest.facility">
  <option ng-repeat="s in facility_services |unique:'facility'" value="{{s.facility}}">{{s.facility}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="nrequest.item">
  <option ng-repeat="s in facility_services" ng-if='s.facility == nrequest.facility'>{{s.item}}</option>
</select>
```

it works yet i'm not sure if this is correct way to do it angular way, since i'm still learning this new toy i was hoping for some directions on how to achieve this using ngoptions, or other angularjs best practice

Comment: not sure what you are hoping to accomplish using `ng-show` on `<option>` tag but hiding them is not supported in some browsers including IE & Safari. Filter the data array instead

Comment: @charlietfl maybe i can use ngif then to remove option from list, can you show an example of how to filter data array ?

Comment: I was also thinking about `ng-if` but the preffered way to load a select in angular is using `ng-options` directive

Comment: @charlietfl yp i saw that on the angular docs but couldnt understand its syntax, its my first week using angular :/